# FCM link not working in desktop notification

Tags: php, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are trying to send a desktop notification calling the FCM rest api via a php service.

We call the `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` service, passing the following payload:

```
"data" => [
    "notification" => [
        "title" => $content->title,
        "body" =>  "notification body",
        "icon" => url('assets/images/logo_3.png'),
    ],
    "webpush" => [
        "headers" => [
            "Urgency" => "high",
        ],
        "fcm_options" => [
            "link" => url($content->url)
        ]
    ],
],
```

The notification is received in desktop (tested on windows 10) but when we click on the popup the link is not opened in the browser.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that we must use `click_action` field, like this:

```
"notification" => [
    "title" => $content->title,
    "body" =>  "body",
    "icon" => "assets/icon.png",
    "click_action" => "https://www.example.com",
]
```

Docs here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref